# Change size of the inline image for Latex fragment in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I recently started using org-mode in emacs for my paper writing needs. One problem I have is that when I render latex equation fragments, the resulting inline images are too small for me to read easily.

Is there a way to scale up the rendered images?

Comment: »when I render«: Are the equations to small in the pdf or in the preview in orgmode?

Comment: You can try to modify the variable `preview-scale-function`. It is documented at http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex/The-Emacs-interface.html

Comment: @KeksDose I have the problem with the preview in org-mode, so I'm pretty sure this is it (or he wouldn't call them fragments, inline, or mention org altogether).

Comment: @KeksDose Yeah, its just the preview inside emacs

Comment: @N.N. I couldn't find that variable in my installation, perhaps because I'm using Aquamacs on the Mac. Perhaps I should have mentioned that :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
;; bigger latex fragment
(plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5)
```

Comment: But this affects inline *and* display equations. Is there a way to set separate settings for inline and display equations?

Comment: For me, this results in an "Error: void-variable org-format-latex-options"

Answer (score 6):

The answer from thisirs didn't work for me.
The post is a bit old, so I guess it worked on an older version of org-mode.
The following worked for me in **Org mode version 9.1.9**:

Pressing `M-x customize-variable org-format-latex-options` brings up the customization editor where I was able to set the scale to 1.5

This is what ended up in my .emacs file afterwards:

```
 '(org-format-latex-options
   (quote
    (:foreground default :background default :scale 1.5 :html-foreground "Black" :html-background "Transparent" :html-scale 1.0 :matchers
         ("begin" "$1" "$" "$$" "\\(" "\\["))))
```